# How to query the Firestore DB properly in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried multiple ways to use .where() with firestore, in the end i just by passed .where() and used .get() then if/else statements to check data. With Javascript it is fairly simple. Python the docs are not easy to understand.

```
doc_reffer = db.collection(u'test')
emails = doc_reffer.where(u'adminEmail', u'==', 'x@x.com') \
    .get()
if(emails == True):
    return "is true"
else:
    return "false"
```

Neither of these work properly, i get a reponse but then cannot check anything on that object. What methods can be used on .where() and how is it used properly?

```
doc_reffer = db.collection(u'test')
emails = doc_reffer.where(u'adminEmail', u'==', 'x@x.com')
    return str(emails)
```

Comment: Have you read this doc https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/2329466637798630851fb70f7a157b8d5edecb6c/firestore/cloud-client/snippets.py#L469-L471 ?

Comment: I have read that but it played poorly with Flask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.stream()` method to [execute the query](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#execute_a_query):

```
doc_reffer = db.collection(u'test')
emails = doc_reffer.where(u'adminEmail', u'==', 'x@x.com').stream()

for doc in emails:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

Note that `stream()` returns an iterator and won't fetch the documents until you start iterating through the results.

You can fetch all the docs, and put them into a dict like this:

```
doc_reffer = db.collection(u'test').where(u'adminEmail', u'==', 'x@x.com')
emails = [snapshot for snapshot in doc_reffer.stream()]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to .where on the name or id of the document though? So search for a document name? I know i can use doc.id. So .where() document name == 'name'

Comment: [Reference for document snapshot.](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentSnapshot)

Answer (score 0):

Using Juan Laras answer i was able to successfully get all documents within a collection where this admin email would exist. Which is what i wanted to achieve. There's pretty much no documentation (simple docs) that i could find for this.

```
 doc_reffer = db.collection(u'test')
    responseUserEmail = 'x@x.com'
    query = doc_reffer.where(u'adminEmail', u'==', responseUserEmail)
    docs = [snapshot.id for snapshot in query.stream()]
    if responseUserEmail in docs:
        return f'found {responseUserEmail}'
    else:
        return f'did not find {responseUserEmail}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem correct. You mentioned that the docs are not easy to understand with python client libraries. This is one of the problems I am trying to solve with [flask-boiler](https://github.com/billyrrr/flask-boiler). With flask-boiler, you will be able to query your objects like this:

```
emails = [x for x in Test.where(admin_email='x@x.com')]
for email in emails:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(email.doc_id, email.to_dict()))
```

Thanks.